# Name Resolution Failure and Network Not Showing

Tags: networking, ubuntu, netplan

Update

---

I reinstalled Ubuntu to prevent spending hours trying to resolve this issue. If the issue occurs again, I will know to write down every single change I make and see if I can pinpoint what actually happens. Thanks for your help!

---

The problem with name resolution has been described elsewhere, but the methods have not helped me - which is why it would be awesome if you could give me any advice. I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 and I'm on a shared network connection in an apartment building.

Summary of events:

- My wired network randomly stopped working last week. When I ping, terminal shows "temporary failure in name resolution". The issue dissappeared a couple of times (network would be back) but kept getting worse and in the last couple of days no network. Wi-Fi experiencing the same problem.

What I tried:

- I was up for an Ubuntu update anyway so I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. The issue is still there.
- Looking at all the solutions online, I found many threads offering to change resolv.conf file. This didn't work because Ubuntu Desktop uses the Netplan yaml file. I have tried editing that file, but it turned out "inconsistent indentation". I checked netplan.io for examples and also other threads to see what I was doing wrong. But I can't seem to figure it out.
- Yesterday, my wired configuration stopped showing up. Checking settings turned out that the cable was unplugged. Tried two different cables but no difference. The message about the unplugged cable went away and now it does not recognize my wired network at all.
- Normally I use wired for Ubuntu and a WiFi extender for mobile. I tried connecting a cable from the extender to the computer and while this worked for a bit, it no longer works. I get the same error.

So what I would like is:

- Find out what I'm doing wrong in the indentation, and whether I need to make changes to my IP address, gateway and DNS;
- Find out why the wired network stopped showing up.

Really appreciate your time.

=================================

```
Network:
 Version: 2
 Renderer: Network Manager
 Ethernets: 
  Enp3s0:
   Dhcp4: no
   Dhcp6: no
   Addresses:[192.168.178.223]
   Gateway: 192.168.178.1
   Nameservers:
    Addresses:[8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8]
    Search: domain.local
```

I tried booting into Live Linux and the wired network connection shows up and is working. I haven' t had my new Ubuntu 22.04 for a week but this makes me think I've inadvertently screwed up something in my settings...?

It should be noted that the code I've copied is probably NOT being applied because when I try to apply the changes, it returns the 'inconsistent indentation error'. I did not use tabs but spaces. DHCP is already enabled and set to true.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/80uvB.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GY7u.jpg

Firewall is inactive. The traceroute command is not installed, and unfortunately when I try to update my packages on the live usb, packages update to 40% or so, then the usb defaults to ubuntu start screen and seems to freeze.

How can I check if NAT is running?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Boot to a Live Linux - does the NIC show up? If not, it's probably going the way of the dodo. Try `sudo dmesg | grep Ethernet` - you should see something like this: `[    1.627598] **alx** 0000:0b:00.0 eth0`. The **bolded** is the NIC driver. Next give command `sudo grep _alx_ /var/log/syslog`. If that shows nothing, try `sudo journalctl | grep _alx_` or `sudo grep _alx_ /var/log/messages` - one of them gives something to analyze. Replace _alx_ with your driver. [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775566/edit) the question to add the outputs as text, not images, just like now.

Comment: Is NAT running and working? How far do you get tracerouting to 8.8.8.8? Do you have a firewall and if so, is it configured correctly? This shared connection, does another user use the same IP address as you?

Comment: One thing to do: your network config suggests you have configured a static IP for your system. Change that to DHCP and see what happens.

Comment: You can't install images yet because you don't have sufficient [repuatation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) yet. Text output shouldn't be inserted as images anyway, but as text just as you did with the NetworkManager config. The "inconsistent indentation" is probably caused by using tabs instead of spaces - apparently YAML is very specific on spaces-only. Check that. I'd also again suggest trying DHCP instead of static IP, and checking the syslog / journalctl / messages to find related entries.

Comment: Further - please don't answer in comments but edit the question for new info. Comments aren't intended for discussions, but for others to ask for clarifications, make suggestions etc. that won't qualify as an answer.